# Python calculator not adding numbers. WHY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculator, calculation

I made this calculator in python that should add whatever value i give it and store the results in a variable. Then if my input in something other than the numbers, it should print the results....It does not give any error, but it prints the results as 0. Why are the numbers not being added even though i clearly added them.

```
while True:
    inpt = input("> ")
    calc = 0
    if inpt == "1":
        calc += 1
    elif inpt == "2":
        calc += 2
    elif inpt == "3":
        calc += 3
    elif inpt == "4":
        calc += 4
    elif inpt == "5":
        calc += 5
    elif inpt == "6":
        calc += 6
    elif inpt == "7":
        calc += 7
    elif inpt == "8":
        calc += 8
    elif inpt == "9":
        calc += 9
    else:
        break

print(calc)
```

Comment: Because on every iteration of your infinite `while` loop, you set `calc=0`. Just put the `calc=0` statement outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each run, you reassign `0` to calc, so you reset the previous run, put it outside

```
calc = 0
while True:
    inpt = input("> ")
    # ...
```

Also you may just convert the string as `int` to avoid such if/else, if it's a digit

```
calc = 0
while True:
    inpt = input("> ")
    if inpt not in "123456789":
        break
    calc += int(inpt)
```

Comment: @AsefDian  You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)